# Vue 3 Composition API: how to run function to retrieve data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a script with a `load()` function that connects to a Firestore database, retrieves a collection and stores it in 'moods' variable. The try-catch block are from a tutorial I'm following, and it's working.
Then I'm trying to convert the moods object I'm getting to an array that contains only one specific value for each 'mood', namely a rating (1-10).

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const moods = ref([])
const error = ref(null)
const ratings = ref([])

const load = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await projectFirestore.collection('moods')
            .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
            .get()

        moods.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
            return {
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id
            }
        })

    } catch (err) {
        error.value = err.message
        console.log(error.value);
    }
    const moods_length = Object.keys(moods.value).length

    for (let i = 0; i < moods_length; i++) {
        ratings.value.push(moods.value[i].rate_feeling)
    }

    const ratings_array = Object.values(ratings.value)

    console.log(ratings_array);

    return ratings_array

}

export default load
```

I'm new to javascript, so this part might not be optimal, but it's working. When I run load() from my Composition API in my view, I get this in the console:

> Array(10) [ 5, 9, 3, "7", "6", "2", "7", "2", "9", "1" ]

Exactly what I need (my goal is to plot these values on a graph afterwards - and don't mind the fact that not all values are integers here).

Now, I would like to be able to retrieve this array (ratings_array) in my view. I'm trying something like this, but to no avail:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Stats </h2>
    <div class="line-chart">
      <line-chart
        :legend="true"
        label="Average mood rating"
        :data="my_array"
      ></line-chart>
    </div>
    <!-- <div v-for="mood in data_array">{{ mood.five_emotions }}</div> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import load from '../composables/stats2'

export default {
    setup() {

        const my_array = load()

        return { my_array, load }
    }
}
</script>
```

But if I console.log my_array, it logs this object:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
<state>: "fulfilled"
<value>: Array(10) [ 5, 9, 3, … ]
<prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
```

I have been fiddling with this for hours and just can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: `load` is an async function but you don’t `await` it so `my_array` will contain a promise. You need to use `await` to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for promise to resolve, so try :

```
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import load from '../composables/stats2'
import { onMounted } from "vue";

setup() {
  const my_array = ref([]);

  onMounted(async () => {
    my_array.value = await load()
  }

  return { my_array }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that was handled with the async await in the load function itself. Alright, clear, thanks a lot! :-)